# Python finding most efficient combination of coins to reach item value

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, list

If i've got 2 variables that contain the price needed, and the value of coins provided in cents. E.G, `coins = [5, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 100, 200]`, and `total = 250`. I've tried a number of approaches, but I can't seem to find anything that works properly.

For example, if i've got `coins = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 100, 100]` and `total = 250` it returns `[10, 20, 20, 100, 100]`, ordering not important.

I've been trying find a solution to this for a while. Thanks for any help

Comment: This problem is asked >= 1 once a week here. Please use the search (maybe with the keyword *coin exchange*).

Comment: Keep adding the largest of the coins you have left until adding one more would put you over the total, then switch to the next largest coin. Wash, rinse repeat until you get to the total or as close to the total as possible.

Comment: @sascha i've been looking, I can't find any answers that are what i'm looking for.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce That's not what i'm looking for

Comment: You might consider sharing some of the approaches you've tried.

Comment: This problem is a special case of the [0/1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem). In the knapsack problem, each item has a weight and a value. For this problem, the value of an item (coin) is equal to its weight.

Comment: @LeoWhitehead https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you would have to sort your coins in descending order, or use reversed(coinList) instead of coinList in the first for loop and vice versa in the second if you would like to sort them forwards:

```
    total = 250
    value = 0
    coins = []
    coinList = [100, 100, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10]
    for coin in coinList:
        if value + coin <= total:
            value += coin
            coins.append(coin)
        else:
            continue
        if value >= total:
            break
    else:
        for coin in reversed(coinList):
            value += coin
            coins.append(coin)
            if value >= total:
                break
    print coins
```

Comment: This approach works with real coins, but not so much with arbitrary coin lists. For example, `total=5` and `coinList=[4,3,2]`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for the feedback. I addressed this with the else clause. Now, for your example, [4, 2] is printed out.